# How to get full path for "../" in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, game-engine, unreal-engine4

I am trying to print full path for "../" in Unreal Engine
but It only returns ".." ,
as i know it is parent directory , and it should return something like C:\Myproj....

```
FString fs = FPaths::GetPath("../"); 
 UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *fs);
```

how can I log full path ?

Answer (score 1):

In the docs you can find: [ConvertRelativePathToFull](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Misc/FPaths/ConvertRelativePathToFull/1/index.html)

> Converts a relative path name to a fully qualified name relative to
>   the process BaseDir().

But that is only full from basedir. So a `C:/something` path you will not get.

Comment: Be aware that the "current working directory" differs depending on whether you are in the Unreal Editor or a packaged build.  In the editor, the CWD is based on the Unreal Engine installation directory (not the project directory).  In a packaged build, it is based on the packaged build directory.  The directory that `..` is relative to is  dependent on this.